# How to obtain man page contents in Python?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, manpage

im running linux and i want to import some man pages to my application.

i came up with this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(('man %s' % manTopic,), shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
if stdout:
```

but its no good, man is displaying only first page and blocks my applicationon

How can i obtain man page with Python?

Comment: What about the formatting? Do you need to keep it, or does it need to be stripped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(('man -P cat %s' % manTopic,), shell = True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
if stdout:
```

instead --
the "-P" option overrides the pager program used by the "man" command.

Answer (score 9):

You can grab the whole output of a command with `check_output`. Furthermore, using a shell is not necessary and might even make your application vulnerable to a [shell injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection) and is [strongly discouraged](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

```
import subprocess

pagename = 'man'
manpage = subprocess.check_output(['man', pagename])
```

Note that using `man` will give you output formatted for a terminal. If you want to have it formatted differently, you'll have to

- call `man -w <name>` to get the location of the manpage,
- probably decompress the manual page,
- feed it to `groff` using the `-T` option to select the type of output you want.

When calling `groff`, don't forget to load the correct macro's.

On FreeBSD I tend use `groff -Tlatin1 -mandoc <file>` to get text output.

Comment: +1 for dealing with formatting and mentioning `groff -T...`, and using `man -w` to let `man` do the lookup and return the path, but then process it yourself.

Comment: Oh, and for mentioning the security implications of `shell=True` of course. Where's my +3 button?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6 there is no subprocess.check_output() :]

Comment: @user775023 Here's the source code for `check_output()` in CPython: [subprocess.py#l549](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e11642068f85/Lib/subprocess.py#l549).